# Hardening WITH ENCRYPTION option for stored procedure protection

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

Is there any way for make WITH ENCRYPTION option more difficult to [bypass](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-decryptor.html) ?

I have to protect the stored procedures code and hide it from other sysadmin of the instance.
I can't manage it with permissions because, as I said, there are more than one sysadmins in the instance.

Comment: If you have a sysadmin who is actively trying to access the code then there isn't anything  you can do to stop them.  What's to stop them from doing an extended event and just catching all statements?  As a security quote I once saw said "they are already on the wrong side of the airlock".... That said, you might look at using CLR to further obfuscate your code.

Comment: Quite simply, you can't hide code from a sysadmin (and I'd have to wonder why you're protecting T-SQL code - this is not cancer-curing algorithms). Maybe you should instead look at whether all of these people need to be sysadmin.